# Deducing graph from image

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

[image: Function]

I have this graph and I have to get the equation. I know there are no easy methods to do this so I am asking for your help. My question is are there any image/data analyzing tools to do this kind of stuff? If not how can I deduce the function from the graph give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "natural" candidate looks to be :

$$y=\exp(1/x)$$

(see image below). I was driven to it because of the "infinite order of tangency" that can be observed on the left hand side of the origin.

At first, I had been attracted by the horizontal and vertical asymptotes, and I wanted to "tailor" (with an "i", not a "y") a function to this initial guess.

See this answer to a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/291756) mentionning a software tool from Cornell Univ. : "Eureqa".

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How did you obtain it?

Comment: I have been working on the famous example given by Laurent Schwartz of a $C^{\infty}$ function with a compact support that is made of such functions. I can find back a reference.

Comment: Yep.  Excellent.